# scraping javascript url but selenium returns empty string

Tags: javascript, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I'm trying to open and then scrape the data from a url contained in a tag that looks like this:

```
<script src="http://includes.mpt-static.com/data/7CE5047496" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
```

I tried using selenium to retrieve/open the url but it just returns a blank string. I think this is because when I directly click on the src url a page opens with a table of the data I want. However when I copy and past the url into a browser it returns empty. Also, each time I reload the page a new src url is generated. Does anyone know why this is happening?

The url:
    view-source:http://mypricetrack.com/amazon/B00N2BW2PK

My code:

```
import time
from fake_useragent import UserAgent
import urllib2
import csv
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import json
from selenium import webdriver

#FAKE-USER_AGENT
ua = UserAgent(cache = False)
headers = {'User-Agent': ua.randome}


#SENDING REQUEST TO PRICETRACKER WEBSITE
product = 'B00N2BW2PK'
page = requests.get('http://www.mypricetrack.com/amazon/'+str(product), headers = headers)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text)
#print(soup.prettify())

#GETTING URL FOR DATA
data_link = []
for tag in soup.findAll('script',{'charset':'utf-8'}):
    data_link = data_link + [tag['src']]
string2 = data_link[1]
print string2
#OPENING URL FOR DATA

driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get(string2)
time.sleep(5)
htmlSource = driver.page_source
print htmlSource
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Javascript won't be downloaded unless you request it with a proper header "Referer".

Selenium is a little bit overkill, you can get it just using python requests:

```
import requests
import re
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
# Emulate a browser with proper headers
session.headers.update({
    'User-Agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_9_0) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/32.0.1664.3 Safari/537.36',
    'Accept':'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,*/*;q=0.8',
    'Accept-Language':'en-US,en;q=0.8,es;q=0.6'
})
# Go to product page
product_page = 'http://mypricetrack.com/amazon/B00N2BW2PK'
res = session.get(product_page)
# find link
link = soup.find('script', {'src':re.compile('http://includes.mpt-static.com/data')})
link_src = link['src']
# Get you JS content
res = session.get(src, headers={'Referer':product_page}).text
```